# Problema con el factorial de un numero en C

Tags: c

tengo este codigo en c que tiene que calcular un factorial de un numero introducido por teclado, una vez haya calculado el factorial se muestra la opción de volver a iniciar el programa para calcular otro factorial.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    
    int num,c,rep,factorial;
    
    printf("Introduzca el numero del que desea calcular el factorial: \n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    c=num;
    
    do{
        factorial=factorial*c;
        c--;
    }while(c=1);
    
    printf("El factorial de %d es %d \n",num,factorial);

    printf("Si desea volver a iniciar el programa pulse 1 si no, pulse cualquier otro numero\n");
    scanf("%d",&rep);
    if(rep==1){
        main();
    }
    else{
        printf("Fin del programa\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Mi problema es que el programa no calcula el factorial, se genera un bucle infinito en el `do while` y se cual es el problema. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tu código tiene 2 errores simple y por eso no funciona. Cuando haces bucle `do while` en la condición haces que el bucle se ejecute mientras que `c=1` eso quiere decir que el bucle se va a estar ejecutando infinitamente si el numero introducido no es 1.

El otro error que tiene tu código es que no inicializas el valor de la variable factorial a 1, por lo tanto a esta se la asigna un valor aleatorio y tu código no calcula correctamente el factorial.

Para solucionar este error solo tienes que cambiar la condición del bucle y decir que `c!=1` lo que hará que el bucle del factorial se ejecute mientras que c sea diferente de 1.

El código modificado sería tal que así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    
    int num,c,rep,factorial = 1;
    
    printf("Introduzca el numero del que desea calcular el factorial: \n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    c=num;
    
    do{
        factorial=factorial*c;
        c--;
    }while(c!=1);
    
    printf("El factorial de %d es %d \n",num,factorial);

    printf("Si desea volver a iniciar el programa pulse 1 si no, pulse cualquier otro numero\n");
    scanf("%d",&rep);
    if(rep==1){
        main();
    }
    else{
        printf("Fin del programa\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Con estas modificaciones tu código debería de funcionar.